# I can't attach a new google sheets to my email using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

During my code in apps script, I created a new google sheet in my drive.
I want the code to automatically send an email to a specific email with the new google sheets I created attached.
after I made the new google sheets in the code I made some changes in it.
I tried 2 different methods to do this task I found online:
the first one attaches the google sheets in the email as a PDF file, but a blank one.
the second method attaches the file as an excel file but again an empty one.
for some reason, I think the changes I make in the new google sheets file only get save after the code finished or something like that.
I will use some help from you guys, if someone knows how to fix this it will be great!
I add the relevant parts of the code.

```js
//creating a new spreadsheet with the new RMA data in order to sent by email to the customer
  var newSpreadsheetName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the copy spreadsheet that will be Emailed to the customer"); //getting from the user the name he want to give the new spreadsheet.
  var folderId = '1RJ9bCqN8bRpzCiU_XGULR9Y32QuSEZQP'
  var resource = {
  title: newSpreadsheetName,
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{ id: folderId }]
  }
  var temporarySpreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(resource) //creating the new spreadsheet in the folder
  var temporarySpreadsheetId = temporarySpreadsheet.id; //getting the new spreadsheet id.

  //pasting the rows to the new spreassheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(temporarySpreadsheetId);
  var newSpreadsheetSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var currentPasteRow = 1;
  var currentCopyRow = databaseSheet.getRange(1,2,1,17).getValues(); //copying the first row values
  newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(currentPasteRow,1,1,17).setValues(currentCopyRow);
  currentCopyRow = databaseSheet.getRange(1,2,1,17).getBackgrounds(); //copying the first row backgrounds
  newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(currentPasteRow,1,1,17).setBackgrounds(currentCopyRow);
  currentCopyRow = databaseSheet.getRange(1,2,1,17).getHorizontalAlignments(); //copying the first row horizontal alignments
  newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(currentPasteRow,1,1,17).setHorizontalAlignments(currentCopyRow);
  for (var i = 1;i <= 17;i++)
  {
    newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(1,i).setFontWeight('bold');
  }
  currentPasteRow++;
  //copying and pasting the other rows to the new spread sheet
  for (var i = 0;i < activeRanges.length;i++)
  {
    var currentRange = activeRanges[i]; //set the range we going through between the selected ranges
    var currentRangeStartingRow = currentRange.getRow();

    for (var r = 0;r < currentRange.getNumRows();r++)
    {
      currentCopyRow = databaseSheet.getRange(currentRangeStartingRow + r,2,1,17).getValues();
      newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(currentPasteRow,1,1,17).setValues(currentCopyRow);
      currentCopyRow = databaseSheet.getRange(currentRangeStartingRow + r,2,1,17).getBackgrounds();
      newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(currentPasteRow,1,1,17).setBackgrounds(currentCopyRow);
      currentCopyRow = databaseSheet.getRange(currentRangeStartingRow + r,2,1,17).getHorizontalAlignments();
      newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(currentPasteRow,1,1,17).setHorizontalAlignments(currentCopyRow);
      newSpreadsheetSheet.getRange(currentPasteRow,17).setFontWeight('bold');
      currentPasteRow++;
    }
  }

  //sending an email to the costomer with the new RMA number and RMA file (first method)
  var temporaryRmaFile = DriveApp.getFileById(temporarySpreadsheetId);
  MailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail,'juganu RMA',"your RMA is being proccesed, RMA ID: " + rmaNumber,{attachments: [temporaryRmaFile.getAs(MimeType.XLSX)]});

  //sending an email to the costomer with the new RMA number and RMA file (seconed method)
  var temporaryRmaFile = DriveApp.getFileById(temporarySpreadsheetId);
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ temporarySpreadsheetId +'/export?format=xlsx';
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  var fileName = 'test' + '.xlsx';
  var blobs   = [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];
  MailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, 'juganu RMA', 'your request is being processed, RMA ID: ' + rmaNumber, {attachments: blobs});
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example, in your situation, when `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is put before the line of `var temporaryRmaFile = DriveApp.getFileById(temporarySpreadsheetId);`, is that the result you expect?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.